# How can I get last inserted ObjectId with golang mgo MongoDb driver

Tags: go, mgo

I am using the mgo MongoDB driver for Golang.

Can I get the last `ObjectId` after inserting a new object?

Or should I create `_id` manually with `bson.NewObjectId`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With mongodb, and `mgo`, you are often expected to generate the `_id`-value yourself using `bson.NewObjectId`.

The [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) states:

> If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before inserting. Most drivers create an ObjectId and insert the _id field, but the mongod will create and populate the _id if the driver or application does not.

Simply, creating the _id yourself is the way to go!